# how to create multiple instance of wcf service using dynamic endpoint with same contract and binding without saving in app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

This is my server-side `app.config`:

```
<services>
  <service name="PokerService.PlayerService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorPlayer">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5054" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint  address="player" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PlayerBinding" contract="PokerService.IPlayerService" />
    <endpoint address="player/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceBehaviorPlayer" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
  </service>
</services>
```

And I am generating dynamic endpoint in client-side code:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PokerService.PlayerService));

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
binding.Name = "NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService";
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.IssuedToken;

ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(PokerService.IPlayerService),
            binding,
            "net.tcp://localhost:5054");
        EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5054/player1"),
             EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("pident.cloudapp.net"));
        ep.Address = myEndpointAdd;
```

For service testing code:

```
var PlayerChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ClientApplication.PlayerService.IPlayerService>(new PlayerHandler(handler, this), binding, ep.Address);

PlayerChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        PlayerChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
PlayerServiceProxy = PlayerChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(User.Instance.userToken);
```

Now I am getting this error

[image: Error]

Any idea?

Comment: not sure if it's a typo, but you're instantiating an endpoint pointing towards service "player1", but I don't see any service defined as "player1"...

Comment: player1 is endpoint name and service name is player.

Comment: EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5054/player1") - it must point to a service that is currently running.  there is no player1 service running from what i can see in your code samples.  The error code is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: i create player1 endpoint dynamically and it is necessary that "player1" endpoint is in server side app.config?

Comment: Emdpoint uri for client should muatch its address on server

Answer (score 2):

Client config file looks as below:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5054/player" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService" contract="PlayerService.IPlayerService" name="NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService">
      <identity>
          <dns value="pident.cloudapp.net"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
         </client>
```

Comment: ok thanks @Jocke .I want to create multiple instances of service using dynamic endpoints at client side but i don't have to save these endpoints in both server and client side app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can host several services on same address (using port sharing,...) - your service endpoint address is define "which of the services you are looking for".

So, as @Backlash also mentioned, your client's uri should point to right server address.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that your have a endpoint mismatch between service and client. Try:

```
new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5054/player")
```

How does the client config file look like?

Comment: nilam gave the client config  @Jocke , its look like this and can you have any idea how should i generate multiple endpoint instance in server side and use in client side?